# How to solve the recurrence relation $t_n=(1+c q^{n-1})p~t_{n-1}+a +nbq$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve $$t_n=(1+c q^{n-1})p~t_{n-1}+a +nbq,\quad n\ge 2.$$ given that  $$t_1=b+(1+c~p)(a~q^{-1}+b),\qquad p+q=1.$$

N.B- Some misprints in the question I corrected. Sorry for the misprint $an+b$ is actually $a+nbq$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let
$$\dfrac{h_{n-1}}{h_{n}}=(1+cq^{n-1})p$$
so we have 
$$\dfrac{h_{n-2}}{h_{n-1}}=(1+cq^{n-2})p$$
$$\cdots\cdots$$
$$\dfrac{h_{1}}{h_{2}}=(1+cq)p$$
$$\dfrac{h_{1}}{h_{n}}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+cq^k)p\Longrightarrow h_{n}=\dfrac{h_{1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+cq^k)p}$$
then we have
$$t_{n}=\dfrac{h_{n-1}}{h_{n}}t_{n-1}+an+b$$
$$\Longrightarrow h_{n}t_{n}=h_{n-1}t_{n-1}+(an+b)h_{n}$$
so we have
$$h_{n}t_{n}=\sum_{i=2}^{n}\left(h_{i}t_{i}-h_{i-1}t_{i-1}\right)+h_{1}t_{1}=\sum_{i=2}^{n}(ai+b)h_{i}+h_{1}t_{1}$$
so
$$t_{n}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=2}^{n}(ai+b)h_{i}+h_{1}t_{1}}{h_{n}}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+cq^k)p\cdot\left(\dfrac{(\sum_{i=2}^{n}(ai+b)h_{i}}{h_{1}}+t_{1}\right)$$

Comment: With successive iteration I got this form $$t_n=t_1~\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1+c~q^i)p+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}(a~i+b)\prod_{j=i}^{n-1}(1+c~q^j)p+a+b +n~b~q.$$ Can it be further simplified to some known form?

Comment: I googled it and found some relation with the q-binomial theorem. But how to simplify that further?

Comment: Please check the 1st expression in your answer, $$\frac{h_{n-1}}{h_n}$$ I think it will be replaced by $$\frac{h_{n}}{h_{n-1}}$$

Comment: No,It's $\frac{h_{n-1}}{h_{n}}$

Comment: That you are taking as an assumption or from where you derive that? What is the reason behind that assumption?

Answer (score 1):

A general first order recurrence relation

> $$ a_{n+1} - f_n a_n = g_n \longrightarrow (1). $$

admits the following solution

> $$ a_n = \left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} f_k \right) \left(a_0 + \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{g_m}{\prod_{k=0}^m f_k}\right). $$

Comment: Can this form be further simplified?

Comment: @Litun: As you see it depends on $f_n$ and $g_n$. So you need to work the problem out and see what you get.

Comment: Please suggest the material to go through the above solution form.

Comment: @Litun: Where did this problem come from? Are you taking a course in recurrence relations or it came from applications?

Comment: from applications I confront with this problem